# How to have a refund after buying on internet

Tags: internet, france

I was victim of a scam on the website "leboncoin"(in France similar to ebay), I wanted to buy a second hand phone.

After several SMS and a phone call, the seller seemed quite correct but after making the bank transfer, I never got an answer and I never received my phone of course.

I have her bank account identification details(for the transfer) but her account informations corresponds to a "Nickel" account produced by the "Financière des paiements électronique" (see the opinions on google) I was only aware of this kind of scam after having made the transfer of course.

The other information (name, city of residence) that she had communicated to me must be false or usurped also I presume.

My bank covers me only on online payments with the credit card but on transfers my bank cannot refund me (I am not covered). The website le bon coin declines any responsibility about this case.

My question: I spent 410€ on a mobile phone I never received and the seller could never be contacted again. Is there any way I can get this amount back? If so, to whom should I turn for refund? and what steps should I take to obtain a refund?

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/ might provide answers to the early stages of this question. I expect that there are actions that would be tried prior to pursuing a legal remedy, and they might be better suited to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious remedy is against the seller. If you cannot identify that person, then there really is nobody else who you can make pay for this. Leboncois disclaims liability for unlawful actions by a seller ([§5.3](https://www.leboncoin.fr/dc/cgu/)).

Comment: thanks, I filed a complaint with the police, an investigation was opened. The seller can be found hopefully i can get my money back.

Answer (score -2):

Just like eBay that uses PayPal, your web store payments to seller must have been via a money transferring organization like PayPal. If so, in Canada & USA buyers cheated by eBay sellers only report it to PayPal and PayPal immediately reimburse the buyer and it has its own system to extract its money from the crook seller. Don't let go of the transferring bank thru which you sent money. Keep talking to them demanding your money.

Comment: The post specified, in the second-to-last paragraph, that the bank doesn't cover transfers for transactions that turn out to be fraudulent.  These are a lot more common in Europe than in the US.  Think of it as writing a check in the US, except it's more secure.  The bank won't refund money you wrote a legitimate check for.  (Downvoters:  Please do not downvote a new contributor without explaining why the downvote.)